# Сумма по столбцу в VBA Access

Tags: excel, vba, access

Столкнулся с задачей: формирую Excel файл из запроса Access. Необходимо посчитать сумму по каждому столбцу в получившейся таблице и добавить их в новую строку.
Перенести таблицу с запросов в Excel таблицу получилось, но не могу добавить сумму.

Возможно ли с помощью VBA внутри Access найти высоту столбца и в следующую ячейку добавить сумму по столбцу?
Спасибо!

Код VBA:

```
Function create_vip_report()

    Dim element As Variant, cell_names As Variant
    cell_names = Array("Äåíü", "Âñåãî", "ÍÅ ìîøåííè÷åñòâî,øò", "Ìîøåííè÷åñòâî,øò", "Ñóììà ïîòåðü,ðóá", "Îñòàòêè íà ñ÷åòàõ,ðóá. (ïðè ìîøåííè÷åñòâå)")


    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set DB = CurrentDb
    Dim RST As Excel.Range
    Set RST = WB.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    Set rs = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM vip_report_table")

    WB.ActiveSheet.name = "îò÷åò_ïî_VIP"

    Set RST = WB.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

    For Each element In cell_names
        RST = element
        RST.Columns.Interior.Color = RGB(252, 213, 180)
        Set RST = RST.Offset(0, 1)
    Next


    Set RST = WB.ActiveSheet.Range("A2")

    Do While rs.EOF = False
        For Each Field In rs.Fields

            RST = Field.Value

            Set RST = RST.Offset(0, 1)
        Next
        Set RST = RST.Offset(1, -rs.Fields.Count)
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop


    WB.ActiveSheet.Rows("1:2").Columns.AutoFit
    REP.Visible = True

End Function
```

Comment: Добавил код в шапку

Comment: не совсем понятно, что вы имеете ввиду под высотой столбца.